# inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle

I have done a program using Java which will store one name field and one image into the oracle database.

I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE.

If i am running the application output is coming that 1 records affected.

Then while trying to see the result in the oracle database using

select * from imagetable1

i am getting the error as

inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB

I am sure that there is  nothing mistake i have done  in the code.

So can anyone tell me what is the solution for this,it means how i will be able see the result in the oracle database.

Code i have written:

```
public class InsertImage 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
          try {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                       "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","askme@123");
              PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into imagetable1 
                                  values(?,?)");

              ps.setString(1,"Binay");
              FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("D:\\Binay\\1355.jpg");
              ps.setBinaryStream(2, fin,fin.available());
              int i=ps.executeUpdate();

              System.out.print(i+"records affeced");
              con.close();
          } 
          catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

Comment: A BLOB for an image seems correct, so the SELECT is processed wrong; it; that code is the culprit. `fin.available()` can be better left out.

Comment: Showing the code that executes and processes the `select` would help. Unless you're just doing that directly in your client, like SQL Developer; how would you expect the binary data to be displayed? You could query the size of the BLOB field maybe, to compare with the original file?

Comment: if i am doing select name from imagetable1,then it is displaying proerly ,if i am doing select photo from imagetable1 then i am getting the error as inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BLOB table i have created as create table imagetable1(name varchar(10),photo BLOB)

Comment: But where are you doing that - from Java, from SQL*Plus, some other client? What would 'displaying properly' mean for a BLOB' value? When I try this, your code is inserting properly (as expected), and querying through SQL*Plus shows the hex representation of the file, e.g. `FFD8FFE000104A4649460001020000640064...`. So what are you doing differently, or not telling us? Are you querying it through Java, but not retrieving it as a stream? Does `select dbms_lob.getlength(photo) from imagetable1` show you a size that matches the original image file?

Comment: i am using oracle 10g express edition and eclipse IDE,coding i have finished then i run my application ,then i am opening oracle 10g there only i am trying to do select * from imagetable1. I am not retriving the image with the help java,nothing i am doing .